# Validar un correo electrónico vía SMTP

Tags: php, phpmailer, smtp, mail

Estoy intentando hacer un validador avanzado el cual comprueba que existe un correo electrónico.

Lo estoy resolviendo en 3 pasos.

1. Resolver la expresión regular de un correo electrónico.

```
function check($email){
    if(!((boolean) filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)))
       return  $email." field is not valid"; 
    return false;
}
```

2. Determinar si el servidor dns existe.

```
public function check($email){
   $domain = $this->getDomain($email);
   if (getmxrr($domain, $mxhosts, $mxweights) === FALSE) {          
       return 'dns servers do not exist';
   }
   return true;
}

public function getDomain($email){
    sscanf($email, "%[^@]@%s", $user, $domain); 
    return $domain; 
}
```

3. Determinar si el correo electrónico existe en su servidor.

Para este punto es donde tengo problemas. Intente usar la librería **VerifyEmail** Inclusive ya parche muchos bugs y lo adapte a un patrón strategy. Pero no conozco bien el funcionamiento de el saludo SMTP para validar la dirección en el servidor.

La librería falla cuando comienza el saludo.

```
$this->_streamQuery("HELO " . self::parse_email($this->from)); 
$this->_streamResponse(); 
$this->_streamQuery("MAIL FROM: <{$this->from}>"); 
$this->_streamResponse(); 
$this->_streamQuery("RCPT TO: <{$email}>");         
$code = $this->_streamCode($this->_streamResponse());         
$this->_streamResponse();         
$this->_streamQuery("RSET");         
$this->_streamResponse();        
$code2 = $this->_streamCode($this->_streamResponse());         
$this->_streamQuery("QUIT");         
fclose($this->stream); 


protected function _streamQuery($query) { 
    $this->edebug($query); 
    return stream_socket_sendto($this->stream, $query . self::CRLF); 
} 

protected function _streamResponse($timed = 0) { 
   $reply = stream_get_line($this->stream, 1);      
   $status = stream_get_meta_data($this->stream); 

   if (!empty($status['timed_out'])) { 
      $this->edebug("Timed out while waiting for data! (timeout {$this->stream_timeout} seconds)"); 
   } 

   if ($reply === FALSE && $status['timed_out'] && $timed < $this->stream_timeout_wait) {    
       return $this->_streamResponse($timed + $this->stream_timeout);     
   } 

   if ($reply !== FALSE && $status['unread_bytes'] > 0) {       
      $reply .= stream_get_line($this->stream, $status['unread_bytes'], self::CRLF); 
   } 

   $this->edebug($reply); 
   return $reply; 
}
```

Dejo el link donde respondieron esta libreria.

[¿Cómo verificar si un email existe en mediante PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/262839/c%C3%B3mo-verificar-si-un-email-existe-en-mediante-php)

Desconozco si esta haciendo el saludo como lo establece el protocolo SMTP, ya lo busque en google pero no encuentro nada al respecto de este.

Se que la libreria esta des actualizada porque las respuestas que espera están en xml y los mensajes que responden los servidores smtp no vienen en xml.

Desde estas lineas falla.

```
$this->_streamQuery("HELO " . self::parse_email($this->from)); // respuesta 16
$this->_streamResponse();    // retorna false
```

Ya intente varias casas pero no se que significan los números que responde la función **stream_socket_sendto** para saber como interpretarlos.

Y la linea que obtiene la respuesta, regresa **false**

```
$reply = stream_get_line($this->stream, 1);
```

Comment: ¿Y qué pasaría si el dominio al que vas a intentar verificar por esa petición DNS te bloquea? Pongo como ejemplo el caso de usar Cloudflare en un dominio.

Comment: Si te refieres a que te bloque por establecer la conexión SMTP. En el estado de la conexión aparece un error o simplemente se agota el tiempo de la respuesta. Con todos los que he intentado la conexión si la establece. Pero no he logrado terminar el saludo. (La mayoría de servicios que verifican si existen los correos de alguna forma lo hacen y esto es la única forma que he encontrado de validar correos sin enviarle uno).

Comment: Creo que al final tu servidor trabaja igual si; 1. validas el correo antes con todo ese proceso o 2. si le envías un e-mail para verificar su cuenta Al final quien va a hacer toda esa chamba de hacer llegar el correo y retornarlo si no existe es el servidor de correo electrónico y no php. Esto solo es una humilde opinión.

Comment: Lo que pasa por lo que quiero hacer esto es no enviar correos electrónicos a correos  que pasen las primeras dos validaciones ejemplo "ñljasdkfjakdfjkjeyuwtdhfioshdjfh@gmail.com" este correo las pasa sin embargo no existe. Y para campañas de marketing debe de ser descartado para bajar el costo. Después de esto investigare si hay forma de saber si mi servidor de emails esta en una blacklist para no enviar correos a todos los correos que estén dentro de ese servidor. Ya tengo varias validaciones de correos con envíos. Inclusive el traker que tengo es también bastante avanzado.